# The right way to deal with a few network requests

Tags: java, android, database, api, http

I'm preety new in java/android.
I'm writing android app, which takes data from online api.
The problem is, I'm not sure if my concept is correct.
So my app send first request, but I need some of respond data to start next request.

Here is some example more or less how it looks right now:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private int key = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        new DownloadTask().execute("url of 1st request");
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return downloadContent(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve data. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           if(key == 0){

               // I know it's 1st request because my key == 0

               JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
               String id = json.getString("id");
               key++;
               new DownloadTask().execute( "url of 2nd request/" + id );
           }else{

               // I know it's 2st request because my key != 0

               //here I'm getting data i need

               // and I'm going to rest of my app
               end(result);
           }
        }
    }

    private void end(String result){
        //rest of my app
    }

}
```

Code is working fine, but I wanted to know if it's proper way to do it.
Maybe you know another way to do that, I'm not asking for completly new code, but maybe some topic I should find and read.

Comment: Yes it's basically that, a cleanest way to do this is to use Library like RXJava and RetroFit, but at the end it's the same thing. You wait for the first call to be done, then you do another call. Here's a good way to do it with RXJava https://medium.com/@DoorDash/synchronizing-network-calls-with-rxjava-d30f7db66fb9. I now you are new at Android and RXJava may be hard to understand but it's worth the try.

Comment: Second vote for Retrofit.  It's not clear what you're using now since you didn't show the downloadContent method, but I'm guessing HttpUrlConnection.  Retrofit has asynchronous stuff built in so you don't have to deal with AsyncTasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it asynchronously, i will recommend you using CompletableFuture's. It is very simple and look like that:

```
CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(() -> yourFirstrequest())
                    .thenApplyAsync(yourInstance::getResponse)
                    .thenAcceptAsync(nextRequestClass::sendNextrequest);
```

or you can separate them by Future's like:

```
CompletableFuture firstRequest =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> yourFirstrequest());
CompletableFuture getResponse = firstRequest.thenApply(response -> someActionWithResponse(response));
```

it is very powerful and convenient framework.
Take a look at the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) or [android specific docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture)